# Get current logical path of executable

Tags: c++, linux

On Linux, how can I get the current logical path of my running executable, that is, the path maintaining symlinks within the path?

I know that I can use `readlink /proc/self/exe` to get the physical path, but is there a way to get the logical one?

I wrote a simple test program, `test.cc` compiled to an executable called `test`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char buf[256];
    readlink("/proc/self/exe", buf, sizeof(buf));
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I have a folder `/home/mdkess/personal/foo` symlinked to `/home/mdkess/personal/foo-1.2.3`, and run the executable from `/home/mdkess/personal/foo`, the program will output the physical path `/home/mdkess/personal/foo-1.2.3/test`. How can I get it to output the logical path, ie. `/home/mdkess/personal/foo/test`

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate. I need to know where the executable was run from, not just all things that link to it (or any subfolder of it).

Comment: I agree that this is not a duplicate. Getting the logical path a file was called with is something totally different from getting all links to this file.

Comment: I think examining `argv[0]` is the best you'll be able to do to get a "logical path", possibly paired with `getcwd()` if `argv[0]` is relative. But the cwd bit likely won't be a "logical path". As you noted, `readlink()` will give you the "real path", however...

Comment: There is no foolproof mechanism. `argv[0]` works well if you're called by the shell, but a C program calling `execve()` can pass anything in `argv[0]` that doesn't have to be related to the executable path at all. This is how i hacked my first unix system, 25 years ago; lesson learned: do NOT trust argv[0] to determine anything remotely connected to access rights or determining which config files to read.